# Admob ios x64 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I'm trying to test Admob Banner on iPad Mini Retina. Now I'm getting this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
>         l002 in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureUtil.o)   "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
>         -[GADDefaultGMSGHandler didReceiveVibrateNotification:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDefaultGMSGHandler.o)
>   "_AudioSessionInitialize", referenced from:
>         -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAudioToolkit] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)   "_AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones", referenced from:
>         -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAVAudioSession] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)   "_AudioSessionGetProperty",
>   referenced from:
>         -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAudioToolkit] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
>         l002 in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureUtil.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
>         -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)   "_AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker", referenced from:
>         -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAVAudioSession] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
>         -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)   "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
>         -[GADNetworkChecker stopNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
>   "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
>         -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
>   "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
>         -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I found a solution which removes some errors. It is to add some Frameworks. List of them:

- AudioToolbox.Framework
- MessageUI.Framework
- SystemConfiguration.Framework
- CoreGraphics.Framework
- CoreData.Framework
- AdSupport.Framework
- MediaPlayer.framework

  But anyway I have got this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)   "_AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker", referenced from:
>         -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAVAudioSession] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)   "_AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones", referenced from:
>         -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAVAudioSession] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)   "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
>         -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add following frameworks **BuildSettings -> Build Phase -> Link Binary with libraries**

```
StoreKit.framework
CoreTelephony.framework
AVFoundation.framework
```

Comment: Checked. In my case it was enough to add StoreKit, CoreTelephony, AVFoundation. Thanks.